# Why has different output of function replace?

Tags: sql, replace

```
declare @tachareName varchar(200)
        ,@a varchar
set @tachareName='fsfhk,fsif,'
if(CHARINDEX(',',@tachareName)!=0)              
    --print @tachareName
    --select REPLACE(@tachareName,',',' ')--The output is:fsfhk fsif 
    set @a=REPLACE(@tachareName,',',' ')
    --REPLACE(@tachareName,',',' ')
    print @a    --The output is:f
```

What's wrong,i want to judge if the string has ',' symbal and repalce it with ' '.

The envirioment is SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of your declaration of `@a` - you have not declared length of variable so it defaulted to 1. Thus returning only the first letter of result.

Declare `@a` as:

`declare @a varchar(200)`

Read more about `char` and `varchar` declaration on [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx).

Comment: There's a suggestion to change this very thing on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=244395)